# Why does this list contain more than one distinct value?

Tags: haskell, random, monads, state-monad

I have code that looks like:

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import System.Random
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy
nextWeightedRandom :: State (StdGen, V.Vector Int) Int
nextWeightedRandom = do
  (g, fs) <- get
  let (i, g') = randomR (0, V.length fs - 1) g
  put (g', fs)
  return (fs V.! i)

weightedRandomList :: (StdGen, V.Vector Int) -> [Int]
weightedRandomList = evalState $ mapM (\_ -> nextWeightedRandom) [1..]
```

QuickCheck confirms that the values coming out of `weightedRandomList` are different and have roughly the distribution that I was hoping for (the `Vector Int` looks like `[5, 5, 5, 10]`, so that `nextWeightedRandom` spits out 5 with probability 3/4 and 10 with probability 1/4).

I was able to get it working by guessing my way though the types, but I'm very confused --- isn't `evalState` getting run over a bunch of different copies of the same generator? Why doesn't the list produced look like `[5, 5, 5, 5,...]`?

Comment: You might like [`randomRs`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html#v:randomRs).

Comment: @DanielWagner That won't weight it according to a given distribution. Also, my main confusion with this question is with the workings of the `State` monad, rather than finding a better way to generate random numbers.

Comment: I understand what your confusion is, and am writing an answer about it. Comments are for commenting, not answering. As for the given distribution -- well, neither does `randomR`. You can apply the same transformation on the infinite list that `randomRs` gives you that you can to the elements that `randomR` gives you. e.g. `weightedRandomList (g, fs) = map (fs V.!) (randomRs (0, V.length fs - 1) g)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you call `put` in `nextWeightedRandom`, the state gets updated on each iteration. So each time you call `randomR ... g`, it is using the generator output by the previous iteration.

In fact, the question itself, "isn't `evalState` getting run over a bunch different copies of the same generator" is quite an interesting one, since `evalState` isn't handed many copies of anything! It is given a single generator, and does all its work starting from there.

Comment: I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this -- I understand `mapM` to be returning something that looks like `[nextWeightedRandom, nextWeightedRandom, nextWeightedRandom,...]`, so I expect each evaluation to return the same result -- am I wrong about that?

Comment: @PatrickCollins `mapM` does more than that, it chains those monadic actions using `>>=` which is defined by the `State` monad. Concretely, you can regard each `nextWeigthedRandom` as a function taking the old random seed, and returning a new integer as well a a new random seed. The operator `>>=` simply concatenates the seeds. In this way, each call to `nextWeightedRandom` has a different seed argument, and can return a different integer.

Comment: @chi Ah, okay. So `(:)` is `>>=` in the list monad?

Comment: @PatrickCollins No, it's `mapM` that replaces `:` with `>>=`, roughly. The list monad is not involved here: this `mapM` works in the `State` monad.

Comment: @chi I understand that --- maybe I was unclear. I meant that when I call `mapM` inside the list monad then I get back a bunch of values joined together by the `(:)` operator. When I call it inside the state monad, I get back a bunch of values joined together by `>>=` -- does that mean that `(:)` is an implementation of `>>=` in the list monad?

Comment: @PatrickCollins No, `:` is not the implementation of `>>=` for lists. Additionally, "a bunch of values joined together by the `:` operator" is a description of *any* list at all, no matter how it was computed; that should make you nervous about attributing that property to the use of `mapM`.